# Why does CREATE TABLE appear to succeed but then fail under DBX?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe, dbexpress

I've got a DBExpress connection connected to a Firebird database, running Firebird Embedded.  Everything works fine so far, but something very strange is going on.

I've got a data module that contains the connection and a handful of `TSimpleDataset` objects representing different tables.  But when I try to add a new table, it appears to work but then fails:

```
procedure Update(module: TdmDatabase);
const
   SQL = 'CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (blah blah blah)';
   SQL2 = 'ALTER TABLE NEW_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NEW_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (blah)';
   SQL3 = 'DROP TABLE NEW_TABLE';
begin
   module.connection.ExecuteDirect(SQL);      //succeeds
   module.connection.ExecuteDirect(SQL2);     //succeeds
   try
     module.New_TableDataset.Active := true;  //fails
   except
     module.connection.ExecuteDirect(SQL3);   //succeeds
     raise;
   end;
end;
```

When I try to create the table, it appears to work, and I can `ALTER` and `DROP` it just fine, but when I try to open a dataset that runs a `SELECT` against it, I get an "invalid table name" error.  If I run it under the debugger and kill the program immediately after the `CREATE TABLE` statement runs, then inspect the database, the new table isn't there.

Anyone know what could cause that, and how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DBX, I use IBX for Firebird, so this is a comment: Make sure you Commit the transaction you used to create the table. Make sure your "New_TableDataset" is activated using a new transaction, it's not activated using a long-running transaction that has a different view of the system tables.

Comment: Other tips: I'd run most DDL operations into there own transaction, commiting after every one of them. There is in fact an option in some tools to "auto-commit DDL operations". And I would definitively not mix DDL with regular operations.

Comment: Maybe use the TSqlQuery component instead of TSimpleDataset which is deprecated.

Comment: @No'am: Deprecated? In which version?  Because it certainly isn't in Delphi XE, and TSqlQuery is not a suitable replacement for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That looks like a pure transaction issue, where `SQL`, `SQL2` and `SQL3` are executing in one (or in many) transaction. And the transaction remains acive at least after `SQL`. And `New_TableDataset` is operating in different transaction, which of course does not see uncommited changes of the first transaction.
2. The issue is not a DataSnap / dbExpress specific, but rather the driver implementation specific. So, good to know what is the driver. And optionally to contact the driver vendor technical support.
3. What to do (pure speculation):

   - Try to surround the command executions into explicit transaction control. That will (may) guarantee, that the transaction is finished after required step.
   - Try to execute `COMMIT` after `SQL` and/or `SQL2`.
   - Try to use `TSQLQuery` instead of `ExecuteDirect`. Hopefully all commands will run in a single transaction.

PS: Finally consider to use different dbExpress driver or even data access library.

Comment: Thanks.  Putting the `CREATE TABLE` in its own explicit transaction worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with ADO, the solution was :

1/ As yet said : execute COMMIT after all your DDL SQL.

2/ When the first CREATE is OK, Make a SELECT query (+COMMIT) on the created table

Comment: Unless this is a driver issue, advice "2" is just useless. And if the driver is that bad, it should be replaced. As for "1", it should be augmented to specify the COMMIT should follow DDL (Data Definition Language) statements - as it stands it looks like the COMMIT should follow all SQL statements, and that's plain wrong, because it undermines the whole concept of using Transactions so multiple operations succeed-or-fail as a group.

Comment: @CosminPrund I know that 2/ seems useless, but in my case it has been efficient, and sometimes the driver can't be replaced so easy,and more : it's easy to test. I am OK with your 1/ remark : I'll edit my post.